# Check if child div with specific data attribute exists in parent section using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I check if a parent `section` has another 'child' `div` with a specific data attribute? Here is something I'll to do:

```js
if ($("#parent").children().data("child-nr").contains("1") == true) {
    $("#parent").css('background-color', 'green');
}
else {
    $("#parent").css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="parent">
    <div data-child-nr="1"><p>N° 1</p></div>
    <div data-child-nr="2"><p>N° 2</p></div>
    <div data-child-nr="3"><p>N° 3</p></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just target the element, and check if it's there by checking the collections `length`

Exact match to `1`

```
if ( $('#parent div[data-child-nr="1"]').length ) { ...
```

Contains `1`

```
if ( $('#parent div[data-child-nr*="1"]').length ) { ...
```

Starts with `1`

```
if ( $('#parent div[data-child-nr^="1"]').length ) { ...
```

Ends with `1`

```
if ( $('#parent div[data-child-nr$="1"]').length ) { ...
```

Comment: Is this valid for "11" and "1" ??

Comment: No, it's valid for `"1"` only, which is what the title is asking for (specific data attribute), even if code in the question uses some non-existing `contains` method

Comment: Seems it wasn't OK for the OP, who accepted an answer posted later ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the elment direct children using `>` selector and use a [`[data-attribute selector]`](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), than check if the result is > 0 like:

Code:

```
if ($('#parent>div[data-child-nr="1"]').length > 0) {
    // div exists           --> yes
    alert('ok')
}
else {
    // div doesn't exists   --> no
    alert('nope')
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xt80p2b0/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#parent>div").each(function(){

    if ($(this).attr('data-child-nr') === "1") {
        // div exists           --> yes
        alert('ok');
    }
    else {
        // div doesn't exists   --> no
        alert('nope');
    }
});
```